# Make bash stop moving to the next line in the script till a shared process ends

Tags: bash

I am executing a command `a` which takes as input a script `input.sh` and runs a binary `program`, which produces some output file `output`. `input.sh` has a line `NUMPROCS={some number}` which specifies the number of processors `program` uses. `a` gives me back control immediately while `program` runs. The output file has a line at the end telling me how long `program` took.

I want to run this in a loop to see the time `program` takes as a function of number of processors. How do I make the control wait for `output` to be generated in each loop (and therefore have `grep` get the correct value) before it moves to line 4?

My script so far is below. Line 3 is how I would run it if `NUMPROCS` had a fixed value.

Some issues: Other users run `program` too, so I can't use `pidof program` and `wait` on it directly.

```
1 #! /bin/bash
2 for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16; do
3     a input.sh
4     E=`grep "Elapsed Time" output`
5     sed -i "/NUMPROCS/c\NUMPROCS=${i}" input.sh 
6     echo $i $E >> result.dat
7 done
8 cat result.dat
```

Comment: Can you get input.sh to write out the result data when it finishes? Or does `input.sh` not work in a way that makes that possible?

Comment: It doesn't. input.sh only passes the values of a few variables to 'a'. But I fixed it by stopping 'a' from giving the control back.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your input.sh script (side note, if that's a command-line command, it shouldn't have .sh on the end - on the other hand, if it's read into the "a" program as a shell include with "." or "source", the .sh is fine) backgrounds its jobs internally and immediately exits, leaving all the subjobs running.  Ideally you'd want to edit input.sh, to have a "wait" command after spawning the jobs (perhaps a behavior triggerable by a command line option).  Of course if you could edit it, you'd obviously want to add a wait to specify the job count on the command line too, and then suddenly everything would be really easy.

Editing the script with sed, on the other hand, really only makes sense if this is indeed a shell-script import, which is an approach that makes it hard to pass in command line parameters (passing them to "a" is easy, but for input.sh, it would need to pick them up from "a"'s internal variables, which is pretty abnormal).  Obviously that's a difficult model to do anything tidy with.  In such a case, your options are to either parse the output(s) to look for lines indicating the several executions are all complete, or to use "ps" and "grep" to count how many are running and go on to the next loop iteration when they're done (there's also a really sick approach where you loop until the system load bottoms out again, but surely nobody would do that).

Editing the input.sh script each time isn't really good, since it means if you run several tests together they may interfere with each other - in rare cases, dramatically.

So, although this is far uglier than fixing input.sh or "a" itself, you could just add a loop like this after "a input.sh"

```
while true ; do
    if [ $i -eq `grep -c 'Elapsed Time' output | wc -l` ] ; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 10  # avoid zillions of greps in a given time interval.
done
```

Without more information about input.sh it's hard to give better advice.  Fixing input.sh itself, or the "a" program, to have an option to wait until subjobs complete, would normally be the preferred approach.

Other notes:

- The "#!/bin/bash" generally shouldn't have a space after the magic number.
- Use "for i in {1..16} ; do" instead - much easier to change (assumes halfway modern bash)
- The E=`grep "Elapsed Time" output` is a *nested* command output capture, meaning that it will try to execute the line output by grep.  This probably isn't what you wanted.
- You can drop the ">> result.dat" and the cat, and instead change the "done" to "done | tee result.dat" for the same effect.

Comment: I solved the issue by deleting the '&' in the executable file 'a', which stopped the control from going to line 4 till the job was done. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: According to http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/ the space after the shebang doesn't matter in the slightest one way or the other.

Comment: Note that linux (nd unix) imposes a line length limit on the interpreter directive.  Old unixen had a limit of ~30 characters, so that space was occasionally critical (in linux the limit is around 127). There IS a line in the kernel code in fs/binfmt_script.c that skips spaces and tabs, so in a functional sense, you're correct.  It's still relatively unusual to see a space there.